# Properly rotate image in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-rotation

I have the following method for rotating images (python):

```
> def rotateImage(image, angle):
>     row,col = image.shape[0:2]
>     center=tuple(np.array([row,col])/2)
>     rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle,1.0)
>     new_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, (col,row))
>     return new_image
```

This is the original picture:
[image: Original]

This is the rotated (15 degree angle) picture that OpenCV returns:
[image: Rotated by CV2]
This is the image if I rotate the image around the center in photoshop:
[image: Rotated by PS]

This are the two roated images superimposed:
[image]

Obviously there is a difference. I'm pretty sure Photoshop did it correctly (or better - I did it correctly in photoshop), what am I missing?

Comment: The X and Y coordinates of your center are swapped. The first parameter of `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D` is the equivalent of `cv::Point`, where X is first and Y is second.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the X and Y coordinates of your center are swapped. The first parameter of `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D` is a point, where X is first and Y is second.